# 16-bit depth image getting corrupted

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, queue, realsense

I am using realsense D435 and taking 16-bit depth data and converting into opencv 16-bit Mat and i am having custom-queue written in c++ where i am pushing all my frames and when i am popping out from queue the 16-bit data got corrupted.while pushing frame into queue i am saving into disk and while popping frame from queue that time also i am saving frame into disk.so from there i get to know frame got corrupted while popping.
Same thing i tried with 8-bit data means while converting to opencv mat i converted to 8-bit Mat instead of 16-bit Mat and while popping 8-bit data.The data not get corrupted.

Code:

```
rs2::frameset data = pipe.wait_for_frames(); 
data = align.process(data);         
rs2::frame depth = data.get_depth_frame();
rs2::frame color = data.get_color_frame();

cv::Mat depth_image;        
cv::Mat fin_depth_image(cv::Size(WIDTH,HEIGHT), CV_16UC1, (void*)depth.get_data(), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
cv::Mat color_image(cv::Size(WIDTH,HEIGHT), CV_8UC3, (void*)color.get_data(), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
fin_depth_image.convertTo(depth_image,CV_8UC1);

cv::split(color_image,channels);        
channels.push_back(depth_image);
cv::merge(channels,fin_rgbd_img);           

camera_queue.push(std::make_pair(fin_rgbd_img,fin_depth_image));
```

Custom_queue Code:

```
inline void push(const T& elem) {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        // wait for timeout while the queue is full
        _not_full.wait_for(lock,std::chrono::milliseconds(5));

        // If the queue is full, remove the old item and add the new item
        if (_queue.size() >= _capacity)
        {
            _queue.pop();
        }
        _queue.push(elem);
    }
    _not_empty.notify_all();
}

inline bool pop(T &elem) {
    bool status = false;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        // wait for timeout while the queue is empty
        _not_empty.wait_for(lock,std::chrono::milliseconds(5));

        if (_queue.size() > 0)
        {
            elem = _queue.front();
            _queue.pop();
            status = true;
        }
    }
    _not_full.notify_one();
    return status;
}
```

So from above you can see that i am pushing fin_rgbd_img,fin_depth_image in queue. fin_rgbd_img is 8bit 4 channel Mat and fin_depth_image is 16-bit Mat. so while pushing i am saving also this 16-bit depth Mat by imwrite function that time i am having proper image. While popping out this 16-bit Mat got corrupted.

Below is the png image while pushing into queue i am saving to disk and it's proper and while popping complete black image filled with 0 is coming 
[image]

Comment: Add some code to your question.

Comment: add code, tell how you recogniize corruption, etc.

Comment: Hi@Micka, while pushing 16-bit Mat into queue i am saving into disk by imwrite function and i am having proper frame and while popping i am saving into disk that time i am not having proper frame.

Comment: Hi@IbrahimYousuf, code added and please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: You are working with 16 bit images - please remember that these can be saved only to PNG, TIFF or JPEG (check imwrite docs). Besides that you have not pasted the most important part of the code - where you saving/loading file(s) and thats where you suspect the error to be. Upload it please if it's not file format issue.

Comment: Hi@michelson, i am saving into png format and i attach the image also this is the proper image and this i got while pushing into queue and while popping complete black image is coming filled with 0.

Comment: please share the code for saving the 16bit, 8 bit images to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that both `rs2::frame` and `cv::Mat` are basically thin wrappers around smart pointers that manage the actual data. When you use the

`cv::Mat::Mat (cv::Size size, int type, void* data, size_t step = AUTO_STEP)`

constructor (or any other cv::Mat ctor that takes a pointer to the data) you are telling OpenCV that you will manage the data, so it does no allocation. Once the last copy of the rs2::frame `depth` goes out of scope, the RealSense library frees the data block, and you have no control over what happens to it.

You might try keeping copies of the RealSense `rs2::frame` frames around until you are done processing, which prevents the Realsense library from freeing the data and is relatively cheap in terms of memory and processing time. The other thing you can do (at the cost of more processing time) is use `cv::Mat::clone()` and let OpenCV manage its own copy of the data, like this:

`cv::Mat fin_depth_image = cv::Mat(cv::Size(WIDTH,HEIGHT), CV_16UC1, (void*)depth.get_data()).clone();`

One final note: you probably should not use the `rs2::frame` class directly, since it is the base class for RealSense frames. Instead use `rs2::depth_frame` for depth images, and `rs2::video_frame` for color or grayscale images. The reason is that using the base class makes it impossible to use features like `rs2::video_frame::get_height()` & `rs2::video_frame::get_width()`. The inheritance goes like this:

```
class frame ...
class video_frame : public frame ...
class depth_frame : public video_frame ...
```